# How to perform a keyword search in marqo

Tags: python, machine-learning, marqo

i have been searching through documents in [marqo](https://marqo.pages.dev/) by passing a query as an argument to the `.search()` method but this returns a list of documents from best to least match. i will like to pass a keyword from the document and i should only get the documents that have those keyword

this is how i currently search:

```
results = mq.index("my-index").search(
    q="keyword"
)
```

this is how the output look like:

```
{'hits': [{'Description': "document_1_description",
           'Title': 'document_1_title',
           '_highlights': best_match,
           '_id': 'd65454db-680c-4f77-8c82-f9aaea66efa1',
           '_score': 0.5562359},
          {'Description': 'document_2_description',
           'Title': 'document_2_title',
           '_highlights': best_match},
           '_id': 'article_591',
           '_score': 0.5176503}],
 'limit': 10,
 'processingTimeMs': 107,
 'query': 'keyword'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is pass another keyword argument `search_method="LEXICAL"` to the `.search()` method

here is how your code should look like:

```
result =  mq.index("my-index").search(q='keyword', search_method="LEXICAL")
```